# Error Creating Data object from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I need to download some JSON for display in a table and am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#insertdata).  I can get the JSON into an array.  However, when I try to put it into an object, I am getting two errors shown below.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    NSMutableArray* latestItems = nil;
    latestItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    latestItems = [json objectForKey:@"items"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    for (int i = 0; i < latestItems.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *itemElement = latestItems[i];
        // Create a new l object and set its props to todoElement properties
//ERROR 1  NEXT LINE THROWS FOLLOWING ERROR:
// CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'IDItemFromServer' 
        IDItemFromServer *newItem = [[IDItemFromServer alloc] init];
//ERROR 2  NEXT LINE THROWS FOLLOWING ERROR
//[IDItemFromServer setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d7dfd0
        newItem.name = itemElement[@"name"];
        newItem.address = itemElement[@"address"];

        // Add this new item  to the array
        [latestItems addObject:newItem];
    }
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: You cannot create objects inherited from `NSManagedObject` calling just alloc init. Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error 1 :**

Instances of `NSManagedObject` must be initialized with its designated initializer

```
- (__kindof NSManagedObject * _Nonnull)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription * _Nonnull)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext * _Nullable)context
```

or alternatively with the class method

```
+ (__kindofNSManagedObject *)insertNewObjectForEntityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
```

of `NSEntityDescription`

**Error 2 :**

If `IDItemFromServer` is not a custom subclass of `NSManagedObject` you have to access the properties with

getter:

```
- (id _Nullable)valueForKey:(NSString * _Nonnull)key
```

setter:

```
- (void)setValue:(id _Nullable)value forKey:(NSString * _Nonnull)key
```

Comment: Possibly this should not be a managed object at all.  If it is a managed object, does it have to be in the data model?  This class is designed to handle incoming data from a server, before saving it into an  entity in  the model and therefore is not in the model.  So maybe I should just make it an NSObject.

Comment: I'm just interpreting the error messages in your question

Comment: You identified the reason for error 1. The class in the tutorial was an NSObject but mine is a NSManaged Object.   For 2, is that objective-C?  Not familiar with the arrows and questions marks.

Comment: Sorry, it was Swift. I updated the answer with the ObjC counterparts

Comment: Awesome.  THx.  Seems like I will have to learn swift...just when I was finally making some headway in obj-c